# Trouble with error 'cannot find protocol declaration'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, delegates, protocols

I got SO questions also same as this and I tried with solution but still its not working for mine so asked this again.

This is my `VCWithProtocol.h`

```
@protocol mydemoDelegate
@optional
-(void)demoDelegateMethodWithSuccess:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
@end

@interface VCWithProtocol : UIViewController 
{ 
   id<mydemoDelegate>mydelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign)id<mydemoDelegate>mydelegate;

VCWithProtocol.m

`@synthesize mydelegate`
```

This is my class where I am trying to use my Delegate

```
@class VCWithProtocol;

@interface VCTOUseDelegate : UIViewController <mydemoDelegate> //here is where it shows error with cannot find protocol declaration

VCTOUseDelegate.m

VCWithProtocol *obj = [[VCWithProtocol alloc] init];
obj.mydelegate = self;
```

I tried with Importing `VCWithProtocol` but not working as well

Comment: What is not working? You are not showing us enough to tell us what is wrong. And yes you should `#import "VCWithProtocol.h"  the @class directive does not import the header.

Comment: I should do both? `#import "VCWithProtocol.h"` and `@class VCWithProtocol.h`

Comment: No just import. And tell us why it's not working and show us the implementation of `VCTOUseDelegate`

Comment: I update the question please check

Comment: It is giving problem while I declare it in .h file then how will I use methods of that delegate

Comment: your VCTOUseDelegate.m should be importing  your VCTOUseDelegate.h, so, and everything that is imported in your VCTOUseDelegate.h file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `@class VCWithProtocol;` write `#import VCWithProtocol.h`

And some good practice Use capital letter for first character of any class name and protocol.
e.g. `MyDemoDelegate` and avoid retaining delegate use

```
@property (nonatomic,assign)id<mydemoDelegate>mydelegate;
```

Comment: I tried your solution with #import but still that problem. in .h file after UIViewController < here where I tried to declare it gives error>

Answer (score 0):

Synthesize your mydelegate, and call

```
[self mydelegate];
```

Comment: Yes I have synthesize it and also did `VCTOUseDelegate.mydelegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add #import "VCWithProtocol.h" to the top of your .m file.

Comment: it needs to be in the header file.

Comment: No,forward declare the protocol using

@protocol mydemoDelegate; 

in the header file.

Comment: But why use @protocol in header and then #import in implementation file, when you can just #import in the header and be done?

Comment: If you do it that way, every time you change the imported protocol the compiler will have to recompile the class (and every class that #imports it). If you do that everywhere you'll make compilation way slower as half your app will need to be recompiled every time you make a change to a header file.

Comment: Inder Kumar Rathore has suggested me to not use @class and #import the class

Comment: In your header file (.h) you should be forward declaring everything you can get away with using @class/protocol. In your implementation file you will do the actual #import. Doing it this way will minimize interdependencies in your source and keep recompilation to a minimum.

Comment: Kirby Todd:  True, I guess I don't change my protocols too often.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic,**weak**)id<mydemoDelegate>mydelegate;
```

delegate always needs weak link

Comment: Most of the time, not always.